# How do I make a nav component appear on every page in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, components

As the question says, how can I get the navigation component (bottom nav bar) to appear on every page?

Can someone give an theoretical answer?

Comment: make the bottom tab navigator your root stack and nest all other screens/stacks inside that stack

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `react-navigation-tabs` would solve your problem for this.
As they have individual bottom stack navigation function where you can pass your menu's and the components that are nested to it individually like an object.

```
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

    export default createBottomTabNavigator({
      Album: { screen: Album },
      Library: { screen: Library },
      History: { screen: History },
      Cart: { screen: Cart },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip commented by @Abe in your question, you can see the example on documentation with nested navigators in section ["A stack navigator for each tab"](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab) and see the [Snack for a live example](https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=web). I hope it helps you.